# Java Create array out of parameter in object creation

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I'm trying to make a simple game in Java. In my main class, I let the player type in their names and how many players will be playing.

here is my code in the main class:

```
{...}
Board game = new Board (playerNames,numberOfPlayers);
        game.run();
{...}
```

Now in my other class it looks like this:

```
    private int numberOfPlayers;
    private Player[] players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
    private String[] playerNames= new String[numberOfPlayers];
    private PlayerHand[] hands = new PlayerHand[numberOfPlayers];

public Board(String[] s, int n) {   
        playerNames=s;
        numberOfPlayers= n;
    }
```

it then initializes the Players like this:

```
public  void initializePlayer(){    
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfPlayers;i++){
            hands[i]=new PlayerHand();
            players[i]=new Player(playerNames[i],hands[i]);}
```

For testing I always set the numberOfPlayers directly in the Board class. Since I want to change it now that the ammount of players is not fixed anymore, I have a problem. I assume the problem is that the Arrays get initialized with 0, as numberOfPlayers is 0 at the beginning. How can I change this?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You instantiate the arrays while `numberOfPlayers` still contains its default value of 0, so they are all empty arrays.

You should instantiate them in the constructor.

```
public Board(String[] s, int n) {   
    playerNames=s;
    numberOfPlayers= n;
    players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
    playerNames= new String[numberOfPlayers];
    hands = new PlayerHand[numberOfPlayers];
}
```

Comment: ok, i did this, but the Player has to be instantiated with name and hands.
i tried it with 
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
   players[i]=new Player(playerNames[i],hands[i]);
  }

But i'm getting a NullPointerException now.

Comment: @Allantir You should probably initialize `playerNames[i]` and `hands[i]` before initializing `players[i]`.

Comment: it looks now like this: `players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
  hands = new PlayerHand[players.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
   players[i]=new Player(playerNames[i],hands[i],);`
should i initialize them differently?

Comment: @Allantir Where do you initialize `playerNames[i]` and `hands[i]`?

Comment: nvm, i got it now, i instatiate them now in the constructor `hands = new PlayerHand[numberOfPlayers];` and then run through the for Loop `hands[i] = new PlayerHand();` the code works now! Am i doing anything unnecessary in it? it seems rather long. Other than that, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
private String[] playerNames = new String[numberOfPlayers];
```

equals to

```
private String[] playerNames = new String[0];
```

because an instance field is initialized with a default value (`0` for `int`).

You should move all initialization stuff to a controller where a size of arrays will be known. Furthermore, there is no need to keep a number of players (`n`) after array initialization (`players.length` will return the same):

```
public Board(String[] s, int n) {
    ...
    players = new Player[n];
}
```

Comment: that is probably the prettiest solution and i will do that

Answer (score 1):

When you create the arrays, their sizes are 0 because `numOfPlayers` is 0 at that point.
 You need to create initialize them in the constructor after you assign the player number a value

```
private int numberOfPlayers; 
private Player[] players;
private String[] playerNames;
private PlayerHand[] hands;
public Board(String[] s, int n) { 
    playerNames=s; 
    numberOfPlayers= n; 
    players = new Player[numberOfPlayers]; 
    playerNames= new String[numberOfPlayers]; 
     hands = new PlayerHand[numberOfPlayers];
}
```